# Bash scripting: test for empty directory

Tags: bash

I want to test if a directory doesn't contain any files. If so, I will skip some processing.

I tried the following:

```
if [ ./* == "./*" ]; then
    echo "No new file"
    exit 1
fi
```

That gives the following error:

```
line 1: [: too many arguments
```

Is there a solution/alternative?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/91368/52074

Answer (score 296, accepted):

```
if [ -z "$(ls -A /path/to/dir)" ]; then
   echo "Empty"
else
   echo "Not Empty"
fi
```

Also, it would be cool to check if the directory exists before.

`ls -A` means list all but `.` or `..`

Comment: I had trouble getting this method to work when the /path/to/dir contained spaces and needed to be quoted. I used `[ $(ls -A "$path" | wc -l) -ne 0]`, inspired by @ztank1013's answer.

Comment: For those who are looking for a one liner :
 [ "$(ls -A ./path/to/dir)" ] && echo 'NOT EMPTY' || echo 'EMPTY'

Comment: Just in case if someone will be looking for "correct/stable" one liner: `[ -z "$(ls -A /path/to/dir)" ] && { echo "Not Empty" ; YourCommandA ; true ; } || { echo "Empty" ; YourCommandB ; }`.

Comment: This checks whether the directory exists, and deals with spaces in the path (notice the nested quotes in the subshell): 

`if [ -d "/path/to/dir" ] && [ -n "$(ls -A "/path/to/dir")" ]; then
   echo "Non-empty folder"
else
   echo "Empty or not a folder"
fi`

Comment: Honestly, at this point, if it's my own system I just write a quick 10 line Python script, symlink it to `/usr/local/bin` or something, and then call it like `if isNotEmpty "$directory"; then ... fi`

Comment: doesn't work for me, bash 5.0, ls from coreutils 8.30, it returns directory is not empty even though its empty

Comment: If you want to check if the directory is NOT empty (i.e. the inverse to the original question) change -z to -n.

Comment: Can you explain why `-z` is used? I saw in this tutorial  - https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-check-if-directory-empty/ - practically the same approach but does not use `-z`

Comment: `/sdcard/WhatsApp/.trash/`  on `adb` is empty but `-z`  will not detect empty state  removing -z will work.`[   -z "$(ls -A  /sdcard/WhatsApp/.trash/) "  ]  &&  echo "there` no op.  But ` [    "$(ls -A  /sdcard/WhatsApp/.trash/) "  ]  &&  echo "there" `
there` maybe  you didnt think of hidden dirs. Update answer accordingly

Comment: @user1874594 sorry, this is very `adb` specific. I'd like to keep the answer more generic

Comment: @ManuelJordan Check the edit history. `-z` was added later just to make it more explicit.

Comment: Macos Big Sur, using zsh.  Doesn't work, even though `man ls` stated `-A` has this intent.  A simple fix was to regex out the `.` and `..` via `-z $(ls -A $tgt | egrep -v '^\.{1,2}$' )`

Answer (score 42):

No need for counting anything or shell globs. You can also use `read` in combination with `find`. If `find`'s  output is empty, you'll return `false`:

```
if find /some/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | read; then
   echo "dir not empty"
else
   echo "dir empty"
fi
```

This should be portable.

Comment: Nice solution, but I think your `echo` calls reflect the wrong result : in my test (under Cygwin) `find . -mindepth 1 | read` had a 141 error code in a non-empty dir, and 0 in an empty dir

Comment: @LucasCimon Not here (macOS and GNU/Linux). For an non-empty directory, `read` returns 0, and for an empty one, 1.

Comment: PSA does not work with `set -o pipefail`

Comment: For my case empty or not exist is the same.  Can add `2>/dev/null` before the pipe to avoid showing error when folder does not exist `No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 36):

```
if [ -n "$(find "$DIR_TO_CHECK" -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
    echo "Empty directory"
else
    echo "Not empty or NOT a directory"
fi
```

Comment: Correct and fast. Nice!

Comment: It needs quotes (2x) and the test `-n` to be correct and safe (test with directory with spaces in the name, test it with non-empty directory with name '0 = 1').
`... [ -n "$(find "$DIR_TO_CHECK" -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty 2>/dev/null)" ]; ...`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev That's not true, at least for GNU find. You may be thinking of `grep`. https://serverfault.com/questions/225798/can-i-make-find-return-non-0-when-no-matching-files-are-found

Comment: It might be simpler to write `find "$DIR_TO_CHECK" -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty | grep .`, and rely on the exit status from grep. Whichever way you do it, this is very much the right answer to this question.

Comment: I like that this doesn't require listing/reading/traversing all files in the directory. Unlike "ls" based solutions this should work much faster when the directory has lots of files.

Comment: Found this question from a search, discarded poor answers until i found this one, tried it, found it didn't work with GNU find, went to add a comment to that effect ... and found i'd already done that two years ago. Although it should be `grep -q .`. Thanks again, Mr Udvari!

Comment: `grep` is slower than `-n`

Answer (score 22):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d /path/to/dir ]; then
    # the directory exists
    [ "$(ls -A /path/to/dir)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
else
    # You could check here if /path/to/dir is a file with [ -f /path/to/dir]
fi
```

Comment: That must be it, no need for parsing ls output, just see if it is empty or not. Using find just feels like an overkill to me.

Comment: `man test` reveals that `test "x"` is equivalent to `test -n "x"`

Answer (score 21):

With FIND(1) (under Linux and FreeBSD) you can look non-recursively at a directory entry via "-maxdepth 0" and test if it is empty with "-empty". Applied to the question this gives:

```
if test -n "$(find ./ -maxdepth 0 -empty)" ; then
    echo "No new file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It may not be 100% portable, but it's elegant.

Comment: This also finishes early in large directories, works with pipefail: `set -o pipefail;

{ find "$DIR" -mindepth 1 || true ; } | head -n1 | read && echo NOTEMPTY || echo EMPTY `

Comment: Was hoping to find a flag that made `find` return non-zero when not finding results, but this is probably the closest we're getting to that. Would at least be nice with an equivalent to `! -empty -exit 1` for GNU though.

Comment: Finally a correct answer. No attempts at parsing `ls` output, not doing anything extra (like listing all files, then counting them), etc. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 13):

What about testing if directory exists and not empty in one if statement

```
if [[ -d path/to/dir && -n "$(ls -A path/to/dir)" ]]; then 
  echo "directory exists and is not empty"
else
  echo "directory doesn't exist or is empty"
fi
```

Comment: note the echo statements don't match the logic of your test (completely)

Answer (score 10):

Use the following:

```
count="$( find /path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l )"
if [ $count -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo "No new file"
   exit 1
fi
```

This way, you're independent of the output format of `ls`. `-mindepth` skips the directory itself, `-maxdepth` prevents recursively defending into subdirectories to speed things up.

Comment: Of course, you're now dependent on `wc -l` and `find` output format (which is reasonably plain though).

Answer (score 9):

A hacky, but bash-only, PID-free way:

```
is_empty() {
    test -e "$1/"* 2>/dev/null
    case $? in
        1)   return 0 ;;
        *)   return 1 ;;
    esac
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `test` builtin exits with 2 if given more than one argument after `-e`:  First, `"$1"/*` glob is expanded by bash.  This results in one argument per file.  So

- If there are no files, the asterisk in `test -e "$1"*` does not
  expand, so Shell falls back to trying file named `*`, which returns
  1.
- ...except if there actually is one file named exactly `*`, then the
  asterisk expands to well, asterisk, which ends up as the same call as
  above, ie. `test -e "dir/*"`, just this time returns 0. (Thanks @TrueY
  for pointing this out.)
- If there is one file, `test -e "dir/file"` is run, which returns 0.
- But if there are more files than 1, `test -e "dir/file1" "dir/file2"`
  is run, which bash reports it as usage error, i.e. 2.

`case` wraps the whole logic around so that only the first case, with 1 exit status is reported as success.

Possible problems I haven't checked:

- There are more files than number of allowed arguments--I guess this could
  behave similar to case with 2+ files.
- Or there is actually file with an empty name--I'm not sure it's possible on any
  sane OS/FS.

Comment: Minor correction: if there is no file in dir/, then `test -e dir/*` is called. If the only file is '*' in dir then test will return 0. If there are more files, then it returns 2. So it works as described.

Comment: You're right, @TrueY, I've incorporated it in the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This won't work if the directory contains a single file named `*`. A pathological case, but I've seen worse.

Comment: @kkm it did work for me: http://hastebin.com/hevumumoma.txt -- Bash version `5.1.0(1)-release`

Comment: OTOH, if it does not work on older Bash (let me know) one could address that case by adding `test -e "$1/*" && return 1` as the first line.

Comment: @AloisMahdal, thank you, good to know, thanks! I usually test features like that with `docker run --rm -it bash:4.3`, for some arbitrary value of 4.3 :) These are tiny Alpine images, fast to pull and not eating much disk space. 'fraid I have no time to test them.

It has always baffled me how such a common problem does not have a simple canonical solution in shells.

Comment: @kkm what's your point?  have you seen the function fail or not?

Answer (score 7):

This will do the job in the current working directory (.):

```
[ `ls -1A . | wc -l` -eq 0 ] && echo "Current dir is empty." || echo "Current dir has files (or hidden files) in it."
```

or the same command split on three lines just to be more readable:

```
[ `ls -1A . | wc -l` -eq 0 ] && \
echo "Current dir is empty." || \
echo "Current dir has files (or hidden files) in it."
```

Just replace  `ls -1A . | wc -l` with `ls -1A <target-directory> | wc -l` if you need to run it on a different target folder.

**Edit**: I replaced `-1a` with `-1A` (see @Daniel comment)

Comment: use `ls -A` instead. Some file systems don't have `.` and `..` symbolic links according to the docs.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I edited my answer after your suggestion. I know the "1" might be removed too.

Comment: It doesn't hurt, but it's implied if output it not to a terminal. Since you pipe it to another program, it's redundant.

Comment: `-1` is definitely redundant. Even if `ls` will not print one item per line when it will be piped then it doesn't affect the idea of checking if it produced zero or more lines.

Comment: Try that on an NFS mount in a directory with 1-2 million files. You'll be pleasantly surprised that a simple empty-or-not check takes 30 min. Sticking `head` into the pipeline, like `(( $( ls -1A | head -n1 | wc -l ) == 0 ))` may be a fix, if only partial.

Answer (score 5):

Using an array:

```
files=( * .* )
if (( ${#files[@]} == 2 )); then
    # contents of files array is (. ..)
    echo dir is empty
fi
```

Comment: Very nice solution, but note that it requires `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: The `${#files[@]} == 2` assumption doesn't stand for the root dir (you will probably not test if it's empty but some code that doesn't know about that limitation might).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: What do you mean? When I do ``cd /  &&  files=(* .*)``, I get an enumeration of all the files and directories in the root directory, which includes **`.`** and **`..`**. So the ``${#files[@]} == 2`` test is valid.

Comment: Yes, this is ambiguous when you don't know whether nullglob is set (returns 3 array entries in an empty dir when unset). And as long as you're setting nullglob, you may as well set dotglob as well, as noted in the [BashFAQ for this issue](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004), then you can just use `files=(*)` and test against `0`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is:

```
files=$(shopt -s nullglob; shopt -s dotglob; echo /MYPATH/*)
[[ "$files" ]] || echo "dir empty"
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/91558/520567

This is an anonymous edit of my answer that might or might not be helpful to somebody:
A slight alteration gives the number of files:

```
files=$(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; s=(MYPATH/*); echo ${s[*]}) 
echo "MYPATH contains $files files"
```

This will work correctly even if filenames contains spaces.

Comment: Using an array instead of invoking a subshell will make this even better.  This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/796116/654416) does that.

Comment: @codeforester, the solution needs to know what are current shell opts. So one would need code to set opts and revert if needed (or figure out opts and count according to them). This will bloat the code and make it less readable. If this part of the code is on a performance critical path, then it might be worth it (or not, needs testing).
For a normal use case where you check one directory, I think this answer is safe, short and self contained.
If you don't need portability between scripts (which possibly use different shell opts), then the other answer is good.

Answer (score 2):

Another `find` solution, (which doesn't rely on other tools), and should be pretty fast:

```
if (( "$(find /directory/to/check/ -mindepth 1 -printf '1\n' -quit)" )); then
  echo The directory is not empty
else
  echo The directory is empty
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of good answers here for simple cases, but this QA ranks very highly in a web search, and many of the answers have subtle failures that may be important for some use cases:

- permissions problems (i.e. reporting empty dir when it's only unsearchable)
- ambiguity about symlinks (`test` dereferences, `find` doesn't by default, `ls` may depend on whether the path ends with `/`)
- answers using shell globbing may rely on options [like `nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) that need to be tested or explicitly set

Here is a function that is efficient for a directory with lots of files, doesn't rely on shell options for globbing, and explicitly tests for permission problems:

```bash
function mtdir {
    # test for empty directory
    if [[ -d "$1" && -r "$1" && -x "$1" ]]; then

        if find -L -- "$1" -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty | grep -q .; then
            # empty directory
            return 0
        else
            # non-empty directory
            return 1
        fi

    else
        # not a directory, not readable, or not searchable
        # if this is unexpected, might want to print error and exit
        return 2
    fi
}
```

This function dereferences (follows) valid symlinks, testing the targets rather than the links themselves (both at the `-d` test, and using `find -L`). If symbolic links should be tested as link files rather than their target for your application, an explicit test should be added before `-d` (e.g. `! -L "$1" && ...`), and `find -P` should be used instead of `find -L`.

The function can be used with:

```bash
if mtdir some/dir; then
    echo "directory is empty"
    # further processing
fi
```

This has been tested and works under Linux and macOS, with edge cases of non-directory files, symlinks, and directories with locked down permissions (i.e. `chmod 0000 testdir`).

You can also test for a non-empty directory explicitly, or an error, using the return code:

```bash
mtdir some/dir
ec=$?
if [[ $ec -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "non-empty directory"
    # further processing
elif [[ $ec -eq 2 ]]; then
    echo "unexpected error: directory not readable or not searchable"
    # further processing
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if find "${DIR}" -prune ! -empty -exit 1; then
    echo Empty
else
    echo Not Empty
fi
```

EDIT:
I think that this solution works fine with gnu find, after a **quick** look at the [implementation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/pred.c?h=v4.6.0#n366).
But this may not work with, for example, [netbsd's find](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/netbsd-7/usr.bin/find/function.c#L444). Indeed, that one uses stat(2)'s st_size field. The manual describes it as:

```
st_size            The size of the file in bytes.  The meaning of the size
                   reported for a directory is file system dependent.
                   Some file systems (e.g. FFS) return the total size used
                   for the directory metadata, possibly including free
                   slots; others (notably ZFS) return the number of
                   entries in the directory.  Some may also return other
                   things or always report zero.
```

A better solution, also simpler, is:

```
if find "${DIR}" -mindepth 1 -exit 1; then
    echo Empty
else
    echo Not Empty
fi
```

Also, the -prune in the 1st solution is useless.

EDIT: no -exit for gnu find.. the solution above is good for NetBSD's find.
For GNU find, this should work:

```
if [ -z "`find \"${DIR}\" -mindepth 1 -exec echo notempty \; -quit`" ]; then
    echo Empty
else
    echo Not Empty
fi
```

Comment: *find* from *GNU findutils 4.6.0* (the latest version) [doesn't have an `-exit` predicate](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py0zL0VBV7cstag4Mz@PiwvCT63ILFEw/P8fAA "Bash – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

This solution is using only shell built-ins:

```
function is_empty() {
  typeset dir="${1:?Directory required as argument}"
  set -- ${dir}/*
  [ "${1}" == "${dir}/*" ];
}

is_empty /tmp/emmpty && echo "empty" || echo "not empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ $(ls -A "$path" 2> /dev/null | wc -l) -eq 0 ] && echo "Is empty or not exists." || echo "Not is empty."
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

**Without calling utils like ls, find, etc.:**

Inside dir:

```
[ "$(echo *)x" != '*x' ] || [ "$(echo .[^.]*)x" != ".[^.]*x" ] || echo "empty dir"
```

The idea:

- `echo *` lists non-dot files
- `echo .[^.]*` lists dot files except of "." and ".."
- if `echo` finds no matches, it returns the search expression, i.e. here `*`  or `.[^.]*` - **which both are no real strings and and have to be concatenated with e.g. a letter to coerce a string**
- `||` alternates the possibilities in a [short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): there is at least one non-dot file or dir OR at least one dot file or dir OR the directory is empty - on execution level: "if first possibility fails, try next one, if this fails, try next one"; here technically Bash "tries to execute" `echo "empty dir"`, put your action for empty dirs here (eg. exit).

Checked with symlinks, yet to check with more exotic possible file types.

Comment: this is a nice one, basically uses the globs suggested in the BashFAQ [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) -- perhaps wrap it in a function to make it more digestable? Also not sure whether the shoptions listed in the FAQ are needed

Comment: This test misses files named with 2 leading dots, for example `..a`

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken, but I think this check should be sufficient:

```
[[ -s /path/to/dir ]] && echo "Dir not empty" || echo "Dir empty"
```

Comment: -1: Bash 5.0 and 5.1.4 (Debian) return true for `rm -r test 2>/dev/null; mkdir test; [[ -s test ]] && echo "true"`

Answer (score 0):

This is all great stuff - just made it into a script so I can check for empty directories below the current one. The below should be put into a file called 'findempty', placed in the path somewhere so bash can find it and then chmod 755 to run. Can easily be amended to your specific needs I guess.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" == "0" ]; then 
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec findempty "{}"  \;
exit
fi

COUNT=`ls -1A "$*" | wc -l`
if [ "$COUNT" == "0" ]; then 
echo "$* : $COUNT"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For any directory other than the current one, you can check if it's empty by trying to `rmdir` it, because `rmdir` is guaranteed to fail for non-empty directories. If `rmdir` succeeds, and you actually wanted the empty directory to survive the test, just `mkdir` it again.

Don't use this hack if there are other processes that might become discombobulated by a directory they know about briefly ceasing to exist.

If `rmdir` won't work for you, and you might be testing directories that could potentially contain large numbers of files, any solution relying on shell globbing could get slow and/or run into command line length limits. Probably better to use `find` in that case. Fastest `find` solution I can think of goes like

```
is_empty() {
    test -z $(find "$1" -mindepth 1 -printf X -quit)
}
```

This works for the GNU and BSD versions of `find` but not for the Solaris one, which is missing every single one of those `find` operators. Love your work, Oracle.

Comment: Not a good idea. The OP simply wanted to test if the directory was empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, to check & process files in directory `../IN`, considering script is in `../Script` directory:

```
FileTotalCount=0

    for file in ../IN/*; do
    FileTotalCount=`expr $FileTotalCount + 1`
done

if test "$file" = "../IN/*"
then

    echo "EXITING: NO files available for processing in ../IN directory. "
    exit

else

  echo "Starting Process: Found ""$FileTotalCount"" files in ../IN directory for processing."

# Rest of the Code
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this approach:

```
CHECKEMPTYFOLDER=$(test -z "$(ls -A /path/to/dir)"; echo $?)
if [ $CHECKEMPTYFOLDER -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Empty"
elif [ $CHECKEMPTYFOLDER -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "Not Empty"
else
  echo "Error"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Question was:**

```
if [ ./* == "./*" ]; then
    echo "No new file"
    exit 1
fi
```

**Answer is:**

```
if ls -1qA . | grep -q .
    then ! exit 1
    else : # Dir is empty
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have missed an equivalent to this, which works on Unix

```
cd directory-concerned
ls * > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

return-code (test value of $?) will be 2 if nothing
or 0 something found.

Note this ignores any '.' files and will probably return 2 if any of these exist
without any other 'normal' filenames.

Answer (score 0):

## More solutions with `find`

```
# Tests that a directory is empty.
# Will print error message if not empty to stderr and set return
# val to non-zero (i.e. evaluates as false)
#
function is_empty() {
    find $1 -mindepth 1   -exec false {} + -fprintf /dev/stderr "%H is not empty\n" -quit
    # prints error when dir is not empty to stderr
    # -fprintf /dev/stderr "%H is not empty\n"
    #
    # -exec false {} +
    # sets the return value (i.e. $?) to indicate error
    #
    # --quit
    # terminate after the first match

}
```

### examples

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eE # stop execution upon error

function is_empty() {
    find $1 -mindepth 1   -exec false {} + -fprintf /dev/stderr "%H is not empty\n" -quit
}


trap 'echo FAILED' ERR
#trap "echo DONE" EXIT

# create a sandbox to play in
d=$(mktemp -d)
f=$d/blah # this will be a potention file

set -v # turn on debugging

# dir should be empty
is_empty $d

# create a file in the dir
touch $f
! is_empty $d

# this will cause the script to fail because the dir is not empty
is_empty $d

# this line will not execute
echo "we should not get here"
```

### output

```
[root@sysresccd ~/sandbox]# ./test

# dir should be empty
is_empty $d

# create a file in the dir
touch $f
! is_empty $d
/tmp/tmp.aORTHb3Trv is not empty

# this will cause the script to fail because the dir is not empty
is_empty $d
/tmp/tmp.aORTHb3Trv is not empty
echo FAILED
FAILED
```

Comment: not compatible with BSD find

Answer (score 0):

Although there are many reasonable solutions here, I am personally not a big fan of most of these answers, as many return a lot of output when returning directory contents.  I was expecting a solution that would better handle directories with large numbers of files, while also one that I think is easy to understand.

So, this is what I ended up with, and thought I would share:

This appears to work OK for me on RedHat:

```
dir="/tmp/my_empty_dir"
[[ -d "${dir}" && -z "$(find "${dir}" -not -path "${dir}" -print -quit)" ]] && echo "${dir} is empty"
```

**In this example:**

First ensure dir exists `-d "$dir"`, otherwise this will return empty (we will also see an error sent to stderr).

However it's likely you would need to test for this separately, as a *"not empty"* result is likely to mean *"contains files"* (which is not correct)

AND

Find: (`find $dir -not -path $dir -print -quit`):

- Find everything in $dir
- Exclude the directory $dir from the resulting output
- Print the first result (something else within $dir)
- Quit immediately (only return the first result).

**BEWARE** the -path parameter takes a "pattern", so if you are expecting special characters (eg: *, [, ]) these would need to be escaped Eg:

```
dir='/tmp/test[dir]'
dirpath='/tmp/test\[dir\]'
find "${dir}" -not -path "${dirpath}" -print -quit
```

During my test, this also successfully found hidden files. (`$dir/.hidden`)

Find returns 0 regardless of whether anything is found, and I don't currently see a simpler way to test this, so:

As per other examples I also wrapped this in:

Empty: `[[ -z "$result" ]]` to test if the result is blank.

NOT Empty: `[[ ! -z "$result" ]]` to test if the result is not blank.

Yes, the braces around ${dir} are not really required, but I thought it best to help handle this use case

```
dir="/tmp/"
[[ -d "${dir}subdir" ...
```